Does it make sense to have object detection model followed by a classification model
So i was working with the  SKU110k dataset and i was required to identify the different items in the shelf as well but the SKU110k dataset only annotated shelf items but did not identify them. So i thought i could create a two-step pipeline with a separate classifier to classify the objects found from the object detection model.
Should i update annotations as per my requirement or will the two step pipeline require less data
Note a requirement is that new items will be needed to classified. So the amount of items required to be classified will increase.
i am thinking something like YOLOV3+FeatureMatching
